# Does ComponentDidMount not work with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to use `componentDidMount` on a project but it only appears to work when the file uses classes.

Comment: There are no lifecycle hooks with functional components + hooks. Hooks are a way to synchronize side effects with state and state changes. For similar behavior, check out useEffect(), which is a general way to sync side effects with state changes, and run effects + cleanup functions https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: You have answered your own question! Look into the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to achieve the same behaviour in a functional component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hooks you can use useEffect to get same result.

This one would work like componentDidMount

```
useEffect(() = > {
}, [])
```

If you put a callback in empty array then it would work when you use that callback

Answer (score 0):

According to the React docs:

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component, but you can definitely
> mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree.

Instead of componentDidMount you can use useEffect instead, with an empty array as its dependency which will serve the same purpose of running code when the component mounts:

```
useEffect(() = > {
// ... code
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer:

*With hooks you can use useEffect to get same result.
This one would work like componentDidMount
useEffect(() = > {
}, [])*

is right except:
*If you put a callback in empty array then it would work when you use that callback*

that empty array is where you would list dependencies that upon change would re-run the function. The empty array turns it into run only once.